# Cannot subset with brackets inside custom function

Tags: r

I'm getting NaN instead of a proper number. Compare code below:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(y = runif(10,1,10), 
                 z = seq(1:10),
                 w = seq(1:10))

test <- function(data, variable){
  x<-mean(data$y[data$variable < 5])
  return(x)
}

test(data = df,variable = z) # NaN
mean(df$y[df$z < 5]) # 4.430517
```

So basically, cannot subset inside function. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `data$y[data[,variable] < 5]` and use `test(data = df,variable = "z")`

Answer (score 2):

If for some reason you want to be able to supply the column name with *or without* quotes, [you can use `ensym`](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/quasiquotation.html#capturing-symbols). Considering your example data:

```
    library(rlang)
    set.seed(123)
    
    test <- function(data, variable){
      critical_data <- eval(ensym(variable), data)
      mean(data$y[critical_data < 5])
    }
```

```
    identical(test(df, 'z'),
              test(df, z)
              )


    ## [1] TRUE
```

Comment: What is the reasoning behind loading an extra package just to do what  `x[, variable]` would do?

Comment: The extra package provides `ensym` which allows passing the variable name with or without quotes. The latter was one issue in the OP, either inadvertently (as covered by @missuse and @Robby star) or purposefully (for which ensym provides a solution).